# Как сделать разметку текста в TextView посередине?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно, чтоб в TextView мой текст центрировался не по левому краю а по середине... И гугле много разных статей и примеров, но я не нашел в того в котором было бы показано как сделать текст с центровкой по середине... В Word это делается нажатием одной кнопки)) Вот на скриншоте текст слева мне нужно его вытянуть на середину... Кто знает как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Указать для `TextView`

```
android:gravity="center"
```

или из кода, с помощью метода

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: При этом необходимо установить 'layout_width' TextView на 'match_parent'. 'gravity=center' центрирует содержание блока в его рамках, поэтому если размер блока соответствует размеру его содержания, то визуально, центрирование заметно не будет.

Answer (score 3):

Укажите `android:gravity="center"` для контейнера (любой Layout - `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` к примеру), в котором находится ваш `TextView`.

Это расположит все объекты в контейнере так, чтобы расстояние от их левого и правого краев до краев контейнера было одинаковым. Содержание этих объектов, при этом не затрагивается.